# Connection between Ubuntu and Nexus 7 does not work well

Tags: nexus-7, music, file-transfer, usb-connection-mode

Following the instruction in http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2004182
(I also see many other similar guides online)
The above method, shortly, is editing the file 
(Do not follow the instructions below for connection, since it omits many steps and only for a description purpose. Using the link above if you want to do connection.)

> sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

And put the device information in the file:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"

It starts udev

> sudo service udev restart

Create mount point and permissions

> sudo mkdir /media/nexus7 
>   chmod 755 /media/nexus7

MTP in Nexus 7 is enabled.
(Do not follow the instructions for connection, since it omits many steps and only for a description purpose. Using the link above if you want to do connection.)

I successfully connect my Nexus 7 to Ubuntu 12.04.

For the first several trials (mount and transfer, then unmount), it can drag and drop files from Ubuntu to Nexus 7.
Now after I mount, I can see all folders and files of Nexus 7 in mounted folder in Ubuntu. But I can't drag and drop files anymore.
It would pops an error window, but with now any explicit information what's wrong.

How to solve it?

Another question: when I succeed in transferring files through mounted media, I transfer music files in Ubuntu to a folder in Nexus 7, such as /SoftwareEnginneringMp3. But all music files were automatically placed in the music folder. How to solve it?
I searched online and find some similar complaints. But I am not lucky to find the solution.

Comment: Could you please include an abstract from "behind that XDA link"? Makes it easier to answer. What tools are you using now, how do you connect the device? MTP?